# Differential equations - mechanics question explanation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, classical-mechanics

I have a mechanics question that you have to solve with differential equations:

> A particle of mass $0.4kg$ is moving at a speed of $10ms^{-1}$ when it enters an viscous liquid at a point, B. Inside the liquid the resistance force is proportional to the velocity, and initially equal to $1.2N$. Apart from the resistance an the weight, no other forces are acting on the particle.
>
> Part A) Show that the velocity of the particle satisfies the differential equation $\frac{dv}{dt}=-0.3v$.

So I got the answer wrong, of course.

My working out is:

$R\:=kv$

$1.2\:=10k$

$0.12\:=k$

By $F=ma,$

$0.4g-0.12v\:=\:0.4\frac{dv}{dt}$

So $g-0.3v = \frac{dv}{dt}$

I don't understand how they managed to eliminate g? Or is my whole process wrong? What am I missing or fail to infer?

Comment: But what about the force of weight? The question says weight is acting on the particle.

Comment: The viscous or otherwise called the resistance force is the only x component force, the weight is a y component equated to the bouyancy of the liquid.  Thus your viscous force acts in the opposite direction to decelerate the mass, thus you have $m\frac{dv}{dt} = -0.12v$ giving you $\frac{dv}{dt} = -0.3v$

Answer (score 1):

To have a compatible answer with the proposed question we have to consider the movement as horizontal.

After entering horizontally, the horizontal dynamics  are described as

$$
m \ddot x + k\dot x = 0
$$

or

$$
m\dot v_x + k v_x = 0
$$

solving this we obtain

$$
v_x = v_x^0 e^{-\frac km t}
$$

but according to the initial conditions $v_x^0 = 10$ and also

$$
-F_0 = m \dot v_x(0) = -m \frac km v_x^0\Rightarrow 1.2 = k v_x^0 = k \times 10
$$

so we have

$$
k = 0.12\Rightarrow \frac km = 0.3
$$

hence the horizontal dynamics are dictated by

$$
\dot v_x = -0.3 v_x
$$